# WCF project trying to recreate database when it exists already

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, wcf

So I am attempting to utilize EF and my existing database in a WCF project in order to add some entities to the database.

**Setup:**

So I have several layers to my solution.

- Core (class library)
- Data (class library)
- Services (class library)
- WCFServices(WCF application)
- WebUI (MVC project)

Entity framework 6.2.0 is installed in my Data, WCFServices, and WebUI project. (picture below).

[image]

So my database models are stored in the core project and my migrations for the database are stored in the data project. My web UI project has no issues accessing the database and using it. I have the exact same connection strings stored in both the MVC project and the WCF project.

**MVC web.config connection string**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SQDCDashboard.WebUI-20190610100239.mdf;user id = exampleUser; password = ExamplePassword;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The WCF project has the following connection string.

**WCF web.config connection string**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SQDCDashboard.WebUI-20190610100239.mdf;user id = exampleUser; password = ExamplePassword;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

As you can see they both match exactly.

**WCF service**

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    public string InsertOrder(OrderDTO order)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                var productionLine = context.ProductionLines
                    .Where(x => x.ComputerName == order.ComputerName)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (productionLine == null)
                    throw new Exception("Production line could not be determined from computer name");

                context.Orders.Add(new Core.Models.Order
                {
                    MaterialNumber = order.MaterialNumber,
                    SerialNumber = order.SerialNumber,
                    ProductionNumber = order.ProductionNumber,
                    SalesNumber = order.SalesNumber,
                    OrderComplete = false,
                    ProductionLineId = productionLine.Id
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
                return "Success";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Error**

So here is where the issue comes in. When I run the WCF test client to test my service, it throws the following error:

> Cannot create file 'C:\Users\eric_obermuller\Source\Repos\SQDC Dashboard\SQDCDashboard\SQDCDashboard.WCFServices\App_Data\aspnet-SQDCDashboard.WebUI-20190610100239.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

This really confuses me because the database already exists.  Why is it trying to create a new one? I am a bit of a beginner when it comes to structuring multiple projects in a single solution. So it could possibly be I just don't understand how EF is interacting between the projects?

I did notice that both my WCF project and my MVC project have their own database files in their respective App_Data folders. I have to say I am not sure how EF uses these files in conjunction with the actual local db, it has always sort of confused me so I may be missing something here (see below).

[image]

**What I have tried**

1. Originally I was using windows authentication but tried switching to SQL Server authentication (which is what I will end up using later).
2. I tried deleting the migrations folder in my project and dropped the database migrations table. I re-enabled migrations, added an empty migration, and updated the database.
3. I triple checked that the SQL Server account I am referencing has read/write permissions to the database.

**Final Remarks**

Again, I have 0 issues using the database within my actual MVC web UI project. My MVC project does use ninject to inject dependencies from my Service project into the controllers, it also injects the dbContext (stored in my data project) into some generic repositories (also stored in my data project), which are used in my Services class library project.

My WCF project does NOT use ninject in any manner, I am directly referencing the dbcontext, as this service is a very simple one and has no need for all that. So I could also see this being the possible issue?

Comment: Don't use LocalDb. If you enter to your local db from SQL Server Management Studio, you will see that is referenced from there. So when you are attaching a new LocalDb, you will got errors as it's already attached. I know, it's confusing, but I hitted the same error. The solution was to use Sql Lite or anything truly portable.

Answer (score 0):

Which DatabaseInitializer you have setup for DB migrations? if you are using '[DropCreateDatabaseAlways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dropcreatedatabasealways-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0)' initializer and have same database for two application running in parallel then that might be causing the problem. 
While your MVC app is running fine, but WCF will fail while booting up the DBContext as it will try to drop and recreate the Database.
Change your database [initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#code-first-initializers) to the one that would fit this scenario. "DropAndRecreateAlways/ModelChange" are not best candidates.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this out tomorrow when I get back to work. I am using whatever initializer is default.

Comment: So I am not sure what happened. But I did not change anything, I deleted the database and re ran the migration and everything worked (sorta). Now I have two databases, the WCF project pulls from one and the MVC project pulls from the other. This inherently lead me to realize if I named my connection string name the same as my db context implementation class name, It would use a single database implementation. I am not sure what happened before but thank you any way for the suggestion! If you could change your answer to somehow explain why what I did worked I would gladly reward you the points!